# Rational points on a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, rational-points

Call a point of $\mathbb{R}^d$ *rational* if all its $d$ coordinates are rational numbers.

> **Q1**.
>   Are the rational points dense on the unit sphere $S :\; x_1^2 +\cdots+ x_d^2 = 1$, i.e. does $S$ contain a dense set of rational points?

This is certainly true for $d=2$, [rational points on the unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_rational_points_on_the_unit_circle).

> **Q2**.
>   If (as I suspect) the answer to Q1 is *Yes*, is there a sense in which the rational coordinates are becoming arithmetically more complicated with larger $d$, say in terms of their *height*?

If $x= a/b$ is a rational number in lowest terms (i.e. gcd$(a,b)=1$), then the height of $x$ is $\max \lbrace |a|,|b| \rbrace$.

This is far from my expertise.  No doubt this is known, in which case a pointer would suffice.  Thanks!

---

(Added, *22Mar13*).  I just found this reference.

> Klee, Victor, and Stan Wagon. *Old and new unsolved problems in plane geometry and number theory*. No. 11. Mathematical Association of America, 1996. p.135.

[image: KleeWagonFig10.8]

Comment: Stereographic projection makes rational points on the sphere correspond to rational points in $\mathbb R^{d-1}$.

Comment: Yes. And the formula of the stereographic projection is not more complicated in high dimension, so this also answers to question 2.

Comment: Does this answer your first question? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90070/existence-of-rational-orthogonal-matrices

Comment: The inverse of stereographic projection does map rational points to rational points.

Comment: I don't understand why Peter Michor's comment got two upvotes. If a quadric hypersurface $X \subset \mathbf{A}^{n+1}$ defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ has a point $P \in X(\mathbf{Q})$, then projecting away from $P$ gives a birational map $X \stackrel{\sim}{\dashrightarrow} \mathbf{A}^n$ that is defined over $\mathbf{Q}$. Restricting this birational map gives an isomorphism between open subsets of $X$ and $\mathbf{A}^n$ that is defined over $\mathbf{Q}$. In particular, the rational point son $X$ are dense in the real locus of $X$ iff the same holds for $\mathbf{A}^n$, which is trivially the case.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the answers.  The connection to stereographic projections is beautiful!  I found a paper that addresses in some form my second question, "Rational Points on the Unit Sphere," by Eric Schmutz, PDF here: http://www.math.drexel.edu/~eschmutz/PAPERS/cejm.pdf .  (He also points out (p.2) that the inverse of the stereographic projection maps rational points to rational points.)

Comment: Joseph: Of course the answer depends on the radius. In order for a rational point to exist the radius has to be in a quadratic extension of Q. 

Comment: Joseph: One more thing. A sphere contains dense set of rational points if and only if it contains a finite set of rational points whose affine span is the entire affine space. Proving this is an exercise in using rational Moebius transformations, generalizing the argument with stereographic projection which is a restriction of such a Moebius transformation. I guess, Klee and Wagon did not know about this group (which is PO(n,1; Q)). 

Comment: Thank you, Misha, for explaining this connection to Moebius transformations so clearly.

Comment: Are the spheres of Problem 10.8 centered at the origin? If so then unless I'm missing something, a necessary and sufficient condition is that $\rho^2$ should be a sum of $d$ squares. Indeed if there is a rational point then applying $O(n,\mathbf{Q})$ which is dense in $O(n,\mathbf{R})$ you get a dense set of rational points.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that Klee/Wagon took an overly complicated approach. The projection idea works well, and I found today that I needed to know this fact about the sphere for another project!

Comment: If the radius  $r$  is an integer express it as a sum of squares $r= \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2 $ with $1\leq k \leq 4$. If the ambient dimension is $d$ then we can find ${d\choose k}$ integer points from the above expression and they should be affinely independent as required in Misha's comment above.

Comment: If you replace the sphere by a different algebraic set, for example the unit cylinder, do you still have such a nice theory?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The question itself has already been answered. Let me just add that in case $d = 3$,
one can obtain a nice picture by marking all rational points with height less than some
upper bound, and projecting this to one of the coordinate planes. The following picture
shows such projection of one octant of the sphere (bound on height: 2048):

[image: a picture]

This picture in resolution 2048 x 2048 pixels can be found at
https://stefan-kohl.github.io/images/ratpoints2048.png.

Larger versions of this picture are available as well:

- [5000 x 5000 pixels, bound on height = 5000](https://stefan-kohl.github.io//images/ratpoints5000.png)
- [10000 x 10000 pixels, bound on height = 10000](https://stefan-kohl.github.io/images/ratpoints10000.png)

Projecting the rational points on the sphere in a [Riemann-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)-like way
to the plane yields a picture like this:

[image: a picture]

The point where the sphere touches the plane is in the middle of the picture.
One feature of the picture is a grid of white circles with mesh size 2, i.e.
the diameter of the sphere. The higher density of points around the middle of
the picture arises from the projection.

Larger versions of this picture are available as well:

- [5000 x 5000 pixels, bound on height = 5000, both coordinates from -6 to 6](https://stefan-kohl.github.io/images/ratpoints5000_6p.png)
- [10000 x 10000 pixels, bound on height = 10000, both coordinates from -8 to 8](https://stefan-kohl.github.io/images/ratpoints10000_8p.png)

Comment: That certainly looks interesting; I can't explain the patterns off the top of my head. Can you make an animation where you vary the height bound? I'd be interested to see it if you can.

Comment: That would be some work. -- Though what you would see is roughly the following: as the height bound increases, the white circles around the points with small height get smaller and smaller, and the points on their boundaries get denser and denser. 



Comment: The picture is essentially the same for the (projective) plane (via stereographic projection). The reason for the white disks is that points of small height `repel' each other so that nearby you only find points of comparably large height.

Comment: @Stefan: This is an entirely non-substantive comment, but I cannot but view your incredibly fascinating image as analogous to meteors impacting the surface of a planet, like Jupiter. 

Comment: Can you expand a bit on how you created this picture? How were the individual points obtained? The shading suggests, that you actually created points on a cube and projected them - which led to an increased density where the corners of the cube had been. If you did not create this plot like that it would be very interesting to investigate the origin of the increased densities.

Comment: @example: Yes, the reason for the shading is as you guessed. I have changed the picture in such way that it uses a uniform upper bound on the denominators. Also I have expanded my answer, showing more pictures.

Comment: When did this build. Used formula?  What meaning has this problem? Ibid formula is quite simple.

Comment: Thank you very much for the change. It is even more beautiful now =)

Comment: In the code for producing the pictures of the 'Riemann-sphere-like' projection to the plane which I added yesterday, I found a small mistake. I have corrected the affected pictures.

Answer (score 12):

Coincidentally, I learnt about the following paper (from 2008) by Erich Schmutz in a talk by Amos Nevo this morning which, I believe, answers both of your questions: 
[Rational Points on the Unit Sphere](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~eschmutz/PAPERS/cejm.pdf).

In particular, he proves the following bound on the height of a rational point $r = (r_1, \ldots, r_d)$ on the unit sphere which is $\epsilon$-close to $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_d)$ for the sup-norm: $$H(r) \le \left( \frac {\sqrt{32} m} \epsilon \right)^{2 m},$$
where $m = \lceil \log_2 d \rceil$.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks! We posted links to the same paper at the same time. :-)

Answer (score 12):

We (with Keith Merrill) recently wrote a paper further quantifying the density of rational points on $S^n$, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.0989. Hope it helps!

Comment: A belated welcome to MO, Dmitri.

Answer (score 11):

With regards to Q1 you can get a finer notion of density by counting the number $N(B)$, say, of rational points with height at most $B$, and consider how this quantity behaves as $B\rightarrow \infty$. I would think of this problem projectively. In this case rational points would be $[x_1,\dots,x_n,y]$, with $x_1,\dots,x_n,y$ integers such that $\gcd(x_1,\dots,x_n,y)=1$, for which $$
x_1^2+\cdots +x_d^2=y^2.$$ 
One could then define the height of a point to be $\max(|x_i|,|y|)$. Using the Hardy-Littlewood circle method, for example, one can prove (for $d\geq 3$) that 
$$
N(B)\sim B^{d-1}\sigma_\infty\prod_p\sigma_p,
$$
as $B\rightarrow \infty$, where $\sigma_v$ is the density of points on the quadric in the completion $\mathbb{Q}_v$.

Comment: Nice answer. I wonder if this statement also follows from http://gauss.math.yale.edu/~ho2/FinalGAFA.pdf (by considering G=SO(n) and H=SO(n-1)).

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the following paper and references therein help:

MR1975458 (2004h:11031) Reviewed 
Margulis, Gregory(1-YALE)
Diophantine approximation, lattices and flows on homogeneous spaces. A panorama of number theory or the view from Baker's garden (Zürich, 1999), 280–310, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 2002.

Comment: @Peter: A lacuna in our libraries here, so Interlibrary loan to the rescue...