# Maximum number of general-position points with mutual rational distances?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, rational-points

Richard Guy has shown that there are six points in the plane—no three collinear,
no four cocircular—such that all interpoint distances are rational.

> Guy, Richard. *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*. Vol. 1. Springer, 2004.
>   D20. Six general points at rational distances. p.185ff:

---

[image: GuyFig14b]

---

My question is:

> Q. Is it known that six is the maximum possible? Or have examples been found in the
>   intervening decade that supersede Guy's result?

**Update**. This question is essentially a duplicate of "[Integer-distance sets](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136925/6094)." Apologies.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136925/integer-distance-sets

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Whoops, you are right, I already asked a version of this question---Sorry! But now I cannot delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a heptagon with all integer distances [here](http://www.wm.uni-bayreuth.de/fileadmin/Sascha/Publikationen2/rare.pdf).