# Lattice radial-step (ratchet) spirals

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, rational-points, euclidean-lattices

(*30Oct13*: Now solved; see **Addendum**.)

---

Define a curve, a *ratchet spiral*, $S(r_0,\epsilon)$ as follows, where $r_0 > 0$ and $\epsilon < 1$.

   [image: StepCirclePi2]
$S(r_0,\epsilon)$ begins with the arc of an origin-centered circle of radius $r_0$,
$C(r_0)$, starting from the point $p_0=(r_0,0)$.
The arc follows $C(r_0)$ until it can jump radially by less than $\epsilon$
to a lattice point $p_1$ exterior to $C(r_0)$.
Let $r_1=||p_1||$.
The process continues, always jumping to a larger radius $r_{i+1}=||p_{i+1}||$ from
an arc of $C(r_i)$ that enters a disk of radius $\epsilon$ around a lattice point $p_{i+1}$.

In the above example, $p_1=(3,1)$, $p_2=(3,2)$, and so on.
Notice that the curve does not jump to $(3,4)$ because the distance is
$5-3\sqrt{2} > \frac{3}{4}$.

For sufficiently small $\epsilon$, the curve remains a bounded distance from the
origin. E.g., $S(3,\frac{1}{8})$ is just a circle:

       [image: NoStep]
(*Added*.) Answering a question raised by Sam Hopkins in the comments, $S(3,\frac{1}{2})$
is not just a circle but remains bounded when the radius reaches $2\sqrt{5}$:

       [image: SpiralBounded]
My questions are:

> **Q1**. For which $r_0$ and $\epsilon$ (if any)
>   does $S(r_0,\epsilon)$ spiral to infinity?
>
> **Q2**. If any $S(r_0,\epsilon)$ spirals to infinity, how fast does $r_i$ grow
>   as a function of its winding number?

Continuing the same example, after $59$ steps, the spiral has
wound once around the origin, and the radius exceeds $30$:

   [image: StepCircle2Pi]
(*Added*.) And here is $S(10,\frac{1}{2})$,
an interesting contrast to $S(3,\frac{1}{2})$ above:

   [image: Spiral eps=0.5]
This question occurred to me while thinking about the [Gauss circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem)
and [Rational points on circular spirals](https://mathoverflow.net/q/141559/6094).

---

**Addendum**.
The main question (**Q1**) is now solved by Abhinav Kumar's answer
to the related question,
[Lattice-point-free buffers around circles](https://mathoverflow.net/q/146398/6094):
For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $r_0$ such that
the rachet spiral $S(r_0,\epsilon)$ is unbounded.
The reason is that, for sufficiently large $r_0$,
for all $r > r_0$, the "buffer" between $C(r)$ and the next exterior
lattice point is smaller than $\epsilon$.
Thus the spiral will always jump radially, since the jump is smaller
than $\epsilon$.
Conversely, for any $\epsilon > 0$, $S(r_0,\epsilon)$ might only
be bounded (terminating in a circle) for "small" $r_0$, $r_0$ less than
some finite bound. See [Abhinav's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/146425/6094) for details.

Comment: Nice question! -- Your last picture shows long sequences of collinear points -- is this typical, and if so, what do you know about such sequences?

Comment: Thanks, @StefanKohl! :-) Yes, that sequence of collinear points was a complete surprise to me (although it makes sense in retrospect). I know little beyond what I have posted---Alas!

Comment: Is there any $\varepsilon$ for which the curve does not remain a circle but nevertheless remains bounded?

Comment: Good question, @SamHopkins. I will explore this a bit...

Comment: Have you written software to generate these quickly in terms of $r_0$ and $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @GwynWhieldon: I have written software. It is not without flaws, possibly even bugs. Quickness depends more on job interference than on CPU cycles. Feel free to suggest an experiment!

Comment: It seems almost like a chain relation for continuous rotation in the plane.