# Lattice-point-free buffers around circles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, rational-points, euclidean-lattices

Let $C(r)$ be the origin-centered circle of radius $r$,
and let $\beta(r)$ be the *exterior buffer* around $C(r)$:
the distance from $C(r)$ to the closest lattice point exterior to $C(r)$:

     [image: BetaBuffer]
For example, $\beta(2) = \sqrt{5}-2 \approx 0.24$ because there are no lattice
points strictly between $C(2)$ and $C(\sqrt{5})$, and this is the largest
buffer around $C(2)$.

I am interested in the behavior of $\beta(r)$ for large $r \in \mathbb{R}$,
as I believe understanding that behavior will answer my question
concerning *ratchet spirals*,
[Lattice radial-step (ratchet) spirals](https://mathoverflow.net/q/145963/6094).

I'll pose a specific question before formulating the general question.

> **Q1**. Is there an $R$ such that, for all $r > R$, $\beta(r) < \frac{1}{2}$ ?

If so, then, for example,
the spiral $S(3,\frac{1}{2})$ depicted in that question is unbounded.

> **Q2**. Is there an $R(\epsilon)$ such that, 
>   for all $r > R(\epsilon)$, $\beta(r) < \epsilon$,
>   where $0 < \epsilon < 1$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bambah and Chowla ("On numbers which can be expressed as a sum of two squares") proved that there is a constant $C$ such that for any $x > 0$, there is an integer between $x$ and $x+ Cx^{1/4}$ which is the sum of two squares. From this it easily follows that the answer to the more general Q2 is in the affirmative. (in fact $x + Cx^{1/2 - \epsilon}$ would do for any $\epsilon$).

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't this give only a bound $\beta(r) \leq Cr^{\frac{1}{4}}$?

Comment: You apply it with $x = r^2$. It gives a lattice point $(a,b)$ with $n = a^2 + b^2$, where $n$ is between $r$ and $\sqrt{r^2 + C\sqrt{r}}$. Therefore the distance to the circle is $\sqrt{n} - r$, but $r = \sqrt{r^2} \leq \sqrt{n} \leq \sqrt{r^2 + Cr^{1/2}} = r(1 + r^{-3/2}/2 ) = r + r^{-1/2}/2$.

Comment: I see. Much obliged.

Comment: Great---Thanks, Abhinav! This resolves my other question as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a comment, not a complete answer.

Suppose $r$ is integral. The distance from the point $[1,r]$ to $C(r)$ is $$\sqrt{1+r^2}-r$$ which has asymptotics $\frac{1}{2r}$ and hence for integral diameters the answers are affirmative.

If $r$ is nonintegral, then the point $[0,\lceil r \rceil]$ is closer to $C(r)$ than $[0,r]$ and its distance to $C(r)$
$$
\lceil r \rceil - r
$$
gets arbitrarily close to 1 (as Abhinav Kumar pointed out in the comments). So for nonintegral diameters one really has to pick a good lattice point inside the first quadrant.